# Como renomear foto utilizando o plugin media capture Cordova

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile, phonegap-buillder

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e esta aplicação recebe alguns arquivos de mídia(vídeos, fotos e áudios) para isto estou utilizando o plugin [media capture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media-capture), porem quando o usuário tira uma foto por exemplo ele gera um nome aleatório, algo parecido com isto `145938172015.jpg`, gostaria quem aparecesse algo assim no lugar `imagem01.jpg`. Segue abaixo o meu código que utilizo para captura da imagem.

```
foto: function () {
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(app.captureFotoSuccess, app.captureFotoError, { limit: 1 });
},
captureFotoSuccess: function (mediaFiles) {
    var i = 0;
    document.getElementById('ArquivosAnexados').value = document.getElementById('ArquivosAnexados').value + mediaFiles[i].fullPath + '; ';
},
captureFotoError: function (error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, olhando no [código fonte do Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/master/src/android/Capture.java#L313) podemos perceber que em determinado momento ele grava a imagem na memoria.

Para isso ele utiliza `getContentResolver().insert` (no Android pelo menos), retornando um ID da imagem. Como seu objetivo não é criar algo do zero em Java para lidar com isso e modificar o plugin vai exigir modificações em todas as plataformas é melhor encontrarmos outras opção.

No caso podemos utilizar o [Cordova Plugin File](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file), que implementa basicamente API de arquivos do HTML5.

Para saber como lidar com ela é bem simples, você pode ver [neste link como renomear um arquivo](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-dir-move-rename).

Então o que você deve fazer é, capturar a imagem com o plugin atual, conseguir seu ID e localização e utilizar o plugin de arquivo para renomear ela para o nome desejado.